# NextJS keeps creating a new connection to MongoDB, when using pages API

Tags: next.js

I was following [this example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose) on NextJS' official Github page, and I've managed to get up and running in my project.

Below is my file structure:

```
pages
 ┣ api
 ┃ ┣ auth
 ┃ ┃ ┣ load.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ login.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┗ register.ts
 ┃ ┣ contact
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.ts
 ┃ ┣ listings
 ┃ ┃ ┣ paginate.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ index.ts
 ┣ _app.tsx
 ┣ _document.tsx
 ┣ _error.tsx
 ┗ index.tsx
```

Most of these api routes run `await connectDb()` before proceeding. Here it is:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import config from 'config';

const connectionObject: any = {};

const connectDb = async () => {
    if (connectionObject.isConnected) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || config.get('mongoURI'), {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useCreateIndex: true,
        });

        connectionObject.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Failed to connect to db', err);
    }
};

export default connectDb;
```

The issue I'm running into right now, however, is that `connectionObject` seems to get emptied out for some reason, when different routes are hit.

I can't be sure, but I think that as long as the route that is hit is within the same directory as the previous route that was hit before it, then the connection will not be reinstantiated. So, if I hit `login.ts` after hitting `paginate.ts`, a new MongoDB connection will be created. Likewise, if I hit `load.ts` after `login.ts`, then a new connection will NOT be created.

I feel like I'm missing something elementary here. What are my options / what am I doing wrong?

I've found a similar [Github issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7811) that seems relevant to my problem, but it hasn't helped me.

[Github discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16594)

Comment: try using a connection pool? edit: nevermind i see what youre looking for now

Answer (score 1):

Each API route is a lambda so each one has its own state

Comment: I changed the `connectDb` function to a regular function, but it didn't fix it. Each route still seems to have its own state

Comment: @MikeK that's not what I mean. You can imagine each API route (file) as a server. so having two API routes is just like running two servers each one has its own global state

Comment: I understand, but is it possible to fix this somehow? I used a custom server instead of their pages API, but I was not able to deploy to Vercel that way. Deployment to Vercel is supported only if I use their built in pages API, but the drawback here is that each file has its own state, as you say. So what are my options here?

Comment: @MikeK the best thing is to use another platform like Heroku. But if you still want to use Vercel you can  make a special API route which will hold your states and you can make requests to it from the other routes to get those states or update them

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; consts are block scoped.(connectionObject)

As per
[Mozilla const documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)
Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let keyword. The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared

So in your case connectionObject remains empty because it's Chang's scope where you update this is block. Hence outside the block it is empty.

Best example to verify is first code snippet in above documentation

```js
const number = 42;

try {
  number = 99;
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  // expected output: TypeError: invalid assignment to const `number'
  // Note - error messages will vary depending on browser
}

console.log(number);
// expected output: 42
```